# Extjs Grid always selects first row, even if i select any other row

Tags: extjs, row, selection, gridpanel

I am trying to create a extjs grid with edit features. i was able to populate grid with my store data. But when i select a row(say row 5), row 1 is selected.

```
Ext.define('Ext.User', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.user',

title: 'User',
//Set the store
iconCls: 'config',

//stateful: false,

store: 'User',

selModel: new Ext.selection.RowModel({singleSelect:true}),


initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [
              { 
                text: 'User', 
                width: '5%', 
                dataIndex: 'userName',  
              },
              { 
                text: 'Password', 
                width: '5%',
                dataIndex: 'password',  
              },
              { 
                text: 'Role', 
                width: '5%', 
                dataIndex: 'roleName',
              },
              { 
                text: 'Last Login', 
                width: '5%',
                dataIndex: 'lastLogin',  
              }

          ],
    this.width = '100%',
    this.height = '100%',           

    this.callParent();
  }
});
```

Any suggestions why this may be happening. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to manage your storing data by selecting a direct row.

Then solution is make your grid able to listen your clicks properly

```
{
        xtype: 'grid',
        title: 'gridTitle',
        store: Ext.StoreManager.lookup('storeId'),
        listeners: {
            cellclick: function (grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {


            }
        },
```

So in the code above you should be able to handle some row with her data.

Hope it will help

Comment: Hi Alexey, No what i am trying to do is to display a grid with delete button, when user selects on one row, we need to remove it from grid. currently irrespective of which row i select, first row is selected